# Is it possible to get the parent folder data in item-adding in remote event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver

Question is it possible to get the parent folder data eg(Title, Custom Columns)?

What I want to achieve is when an user add an item i could pre-populate columns with data i want.

I've manage to create this in ItemAdded so basically i need to get the ItemID so i could get the parent folder but since i need to do this in ItemAdding the ItemId still doesn't exist.

Is there any way i could get the parent folder data using the ItemAdding Remote Event Reciever?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In ItemAdding event recievers should be parent folder like this:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
       base.ItemAdding(properties);

       //file doesn't exist, but here is the parent folder
       SPFolder f = properties.Web.GetFile(properties.AfterUrl).ParentFolder;

       //you can work with this property
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.ParentFolder.Url)
       {
            //code for populate columns
       }

}
```